# Bootstrap nav-tab and pils

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to edit the color of a bootstrap nav-tab so when I click of on specific tab active tab the colour changes.

Does anyone have an idea on how to do this.

Comment: why you dont use css?

Answer (score 1):

If you got nothing against CSS, 
you could try it using [StyleBootstrap](http://stylebootstrap.info/)